# Pass a closure from JavaScript to Swift using WebView

Tags: macos, swift, webview, webkit

everyone,

I am writing a sample for hybrid Mac OSX application.
HTML + JavaScript as View and Swift as controller.

JavaScript code should be able to set callback which will be triggered from swift side at some point of program execution.

JavaScript code

```
...
controller.setCallback(function() { /* do something useful */ })
...
```

Swift implementation of setCallback

```
func setCallback(var callback: WebScriptObject!) {
        JSObjectCallAsFunction(...)
}
```

JSObjectCallAsFunction need JSObject! as argument.

```
var object = callback.JSObject()
```

But now object is Unmanaged type. How should i make it JSObject! ?

Comment: So you want to recognize when a javascript function is done?

Comment: I just need to execute it. As I understant I should take WebScriptObject as function argument and call JSObjectCallAsFunction for JSObject retrieved from WebScriptObject

Comment: heres a github project that passes values from javascript to swift: https://github.com/liqichao/wkwebview-test/blob/master/ios-test/ios-test/ViewController.swift